# How to understand this running train sentence?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067116/synopsis)

> ....Nicoli then kills the conductor who tries to intervene, and the
>   crowd on the train flees

Actually train is in motion, but in this sentence says crowd on the train flees, how crowd flees in running train ?

How to understand this running train sentence ?

Comment: They can go to the back of the wagon. Sometimes, wagons are connected, and they could just move back from the scene as much as possible, from one wagon to the next.

Comment: See this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzEloJ5venk), 4:26-5:10.

Answer (score 2):

> and the crowd on the train flees

The crowd on the train "flees" the section of the train where the conductor is killed.  It could mean people jumped from the train, but here it means they [ran to a different section of the train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzEloJ5venk&t=4m51s).

If they had actually jumped off the train, the author probably would have written

> and the crowd flees the train